# javax.swing.JComboBox cannot be cast to javax.swing.JButton

Tags: java, swing

Here's the code I am using:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    JButton buttonPressed = (JButton) arg0.getSource();
    JComboBox selectedOption = (JComboBox) arg0.getSource();

    if (buttonPressed.getText() == "Spam!") {
        if(emailModeBoolean)
            sendSpam(sendBox.getText(), "Not Spam", messageBox.getText());
        else
            sendTextMessage(sendBox.getText(), messageBox.getText());
    }
    if(selectedOption.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Phone Mode") {
        emailModeBoolean = false;
    } else if(selectedOption.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Email Mode"){
        emailModeBoolean = true;
    }
}
```

It throws this error when I try to change the JComboBox from "Phone Mode" to "Email Mode":

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JComboBox cannot be cast to javax.swing.JButton
at Spammer.actionPerformed(Spammer.java:77)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Where is your ActionListener added? On what component?

Comment: Lets start with `buttonPressed.getText() == "Spam!")` isn't how `String`s are compared, use `"Spam!".equals(buttonPressed.getText())`

Comment: Which line is line 77?

Comment: Well, obviously, `JButton buttonPressed = (JButton) arg0.getSource();` is a problem.  What have you attached the `ActionListener` to?

Comment: I see `(JButton) arg0.getSource();` and `(JComboBox) arg0.getSource()`. It can't be both. Which one is it? (arg0.getSource() I mean).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @MadProgrammer for the buttons, I used `[buttonnamegoeshere].addActionListener(this)`. Same for the JComboBox.

Comment: Lol, my post got downvoted ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You could...

Use a separate `ActionListener` for both the button and combobox...

```
aButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // Button specific code
    }
});
aComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // Combobox specific code
    }
});
```

## You could...

Use `instanceof` to determine what type of object you are dealing with...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) {
        // Button specific code
    } else if (soruce instanceof JComboBox) {
        // Combobox specific code
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! First suggestion worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
JButton buttonPressed = (JButton) arg0.getSource();
JComboBox selectedOption = (JComboBox) arg0.getSource();
```

so on the same call you're trying to cast the received value as **both** `JButton` and `JComboBox`.

If you indeed have the same `ActionListener` assigned to two different controls, then you need to have logic to distinguish between them by using something like `typeof` or `getClass()` on your target.

You also may want to work through [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) tutorial.

Comment: `instanceof` would be simpler

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Yes, indeed.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to apply a different ActionListener to the JComboBox, how would I use that? For the JButton I have, for both buttons, `[buttonname].addActionListener(this);`. Should I use different parameters for the JComboBox?

Comment: @LucasBaizer - Yes, you can attach different listeners to different components. You will not be able to use `this` though. Use either separate classes that implement listener interface or anononymous classes as in [MadProgrammer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872245/2055998).